# Rasa Action Server failing with ModuleNotFound error in Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

I am trying to deploy a Rasa server and Rasa action server and it fails with the error

```
2023-08-21 13:38:47 INFO     rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Starting action endpoint server...
2023-08-21 13:38:47 ERROR    rasa_sdk.executor  - Failed to register package 'actions'.
.
.
.
  File "/app/actions/botdb.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rasa.core.tracker_store import TrackerStore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa'
```

Content of my Docker Compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  # app:
  #   build: 
  #     context: ./frontends
  #   networks:
  #     - admission-bot
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:main-spacy-en
    container_name: rasa
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command:
      - run
      - --debug
      - --enable-api
      - --cors
      - "*"
    networks:
      - admission-bot

  rasa-action_server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./actions/Dockerfile
    image: rasa-action_server
    container_name: rasa-action-server
    working_dir: /app
    command:
      - start
      - --debug
      - --actions
      - actions
      - --cors
      - "*"
    networks:
      - admission-bot
    ports:
      - 5055:5055
    volumes:
      - ./actions:/app/actions
    depends_on:
      - rasa

networks:
  admission-bot:
    name: admission-bot
    driver: bridge
```

The action server Dockerfile:

```
# Extend the official Rasa SDK image
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.3.0

# Change back to root user to install dependencies
USER root

# To install packages from PyPI
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests

# Switch back to non-root to run code
USER $user
```

After running `docker compose up -d --force-recreate` two containers are correctly created:

[image]

The Rasa server is up

[image]

But the `action_server` container does not come and the logs show the error above.

[image]

Kindly confirm what I might be doing wrong.

Just to add, if I run the action_server command locally `rasa run actions --cors "*" --debug` , it executes fine.

This is my folder structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── actions
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── actions.py
│   └── botdb.py
├── config.yml
├── credentials.yml
├── data
│   ├── nlu.yml
│   ├── rules.yml
│   └── stories.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── domain.yml
├── endpoints.yml
├── frontends
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.html
│   └── static
├── graph.html
├── models
├── runrasa.sh
├── tests
  └── test_stories.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing rasa in the `rasa-action_server` Dockerfile. The final Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Extend the official Rasa SDK image
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.3.0

# Change back to root user to install dependencies
USER root

# To install packages from PyPI
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests rasa

# Switch back to non-root to run code
USER $user
```